# SQL Server difference between two rows in union with source data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two rows of data that come from a pivoted query (but for the sake of simplicity I wrote it here 
as if the data came from a table (that has two rows). It looks something like this:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
ZZZ     BBB     1       2
ZZZ     CCC     3       4
```

which would correspond with the alias "a" in the first part of my query (right before the union)

What I need is a final row on the bottom, the difference between BBB and CCC

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
ZZZ     BBB     1       2
ZZZ     CCC     3       4
NULL    NULL    -2      -2
```

I did it with this query (which is working fine), but it seems like a fair bit of work to get a difference. Is there a simpler way? 
I know that using group by with rollup you can get the sum total but I am not familiar with anything for differences, or even something like Oracle's model clause in SQL Server.

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from
(  
    select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4 from data as a 

    union

    (
        select null, null, b.col3 - c.col3, b.col4 - c.col4
        from data as b 
        join data as c on c.col2 = 'BBB' and b.col2 = 'CCC' 
    )
) as data_with_difference
```

Comment: Why not display the "C" values as negative numbers?

Comment: This kind of thing is best done on a front end application, which is why there's no "easy" way to do it in SQL.

Comment: The reason that there is no aggregate function for differences is because it wouldn't make any sense. Because subtraction is not commutative or associative. What would you expect if there were three rows? What if they came out in a different order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple to re-write the query so the subquery only appears once:

```
with a as (
      select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4 from data 
     )
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4
from a
union all
select NULL, NULL,
       sum(case when a.col2 = 'BBB' then a.col3 
                when a.col2 = 'CCC' then - a.col3
            end),
       sum(case when a.col2 = 'BBB' then a.col4
                when a.col2 = 'CCC' then - a.col4
            end)
from a;
```

If `col3` and `col4` had the appropriate signs, then it would simply be:

```
select col1, col2, sum(col3) as col3, sum(col4) as col4
from <whatever>
group by grouping sets ((col1, col2), ());
```

SQL readily handles and supports the creation of subtotals.  The problem is that the columns do not have the correct signs for simply adding the values.

Comment: Regarding the subtotal bit, the columns don't have the correct signs for simple addition because I need them that way. Am I missing something simple? In any case great answer, thanks for your help.